# Como crear procedimiento almacenado para un INSERT

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Recién empiezo con el tema de procedimientos almacenados y necesito ejecutar la siguiente query dentro de un procedimiento almacenado para luego ejecutar este procedimiento almacenado con una frecuencia que se le indique. Esto lo puedo hacer de forma sencilla mediante un job de SQL Server.

```
INSERT INTO TK_DT_RECORDS(
    [TK_DT_RECORDS_ID],
    [ACTIVITY_DATE],
    [CONTENT],
    [TK_HD_TICKETS_ID],
    [NOTE],
    [USER_UPDATE],
    [TK_CT_STATUS_ID],
    [TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID],
    [TK_CT_SERVICES_ID],
    [TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID],
    [TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID],
    [TK_CT_SUBSERVICES_ID]
)
SELECT 
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_DT_RECORDS_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[ACTIVITY_DATE],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[CONTENT],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_HD_TICKETS_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[NOTE],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[USER_UPDATE],
    'CDO',
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_CT_SERVICES_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_CT_SUBSERVICES_ID]
FROM TK_HD_TICKETS AS TICKETS
INNER JOIN TK_DT_RECORDS 
    ON TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
WHERE 
    TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID = (
        SELECT MAX (TK_DT_RECORDS_ID) 
        FROM TK_DT_RECORDS 
        WHERE TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID 
    )
    AND (TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_CT_STATUS_ID = 'TMN') 
    AND (TK_DT_RECORDS.ACTIVITY_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE()))
```

Según la información que consulte lo más óptimo es realizar un procedimiento almacenado que ejecute mi consulta, detectando los casos existentes y que realice sus acciones pertinentes.

Comment: Solo quieres saber como crear el sp?

Comment: Saber como y la query que publique meterla en un sp

Comment: Claro te anexo un ejemplo y cualquier duda me dices

Answer (score 0):

Hola aquí tienes un ejemplo de procedimiento almacenado que incluyes las consultas de `Insert` y `Update`.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `usp_AddUpdateAgency`(IN `_agencia_id` INT, IN `_address_id` INT, IN `_impuesto_lb` DOUBLE, IN `_agency_name` TEXT, OUT `agencia_id_Out` INT, OUT `errormessage` TEXT, OUT `numberOfRowsModified` INT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
                @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;
            SET @full_error = CONCAT("ERROR ", @errno, " (", @sqlstate, "): ", @text);
            set errormessage = @full_error;

        END;

    if not (_agencia_id is null) then
        UPDATE agencia
            SET
            agencia_id = _agencia_id ,
            address_id = _address_id ,
            impuesto_lb = _impuesto_lb,
            agencia_name = _agency_name
        WHERE agencia_id = _agencia_id;

        set numberOfRowsModified = (SELECT ROW_COUNT()) ;
        set agencia_id_Out = _agencia_id ;


    else

        INSERT INTO agencia
            (address_id,
            impuesto_lb,
            agencia_name
            )
        VALUES
            ( _address_id, _impuesto_lb, _agency_name);

         set numberOfRowsModified = (SELECT ROW_COUNT()) ;
         SET agencia_id_Out = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    end if;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Eso es MySQL y el OP pone SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo segun lo que necesitas aqui te dejo un ejemplo con documentacion interna para que cuando llegue otra persona pueda saber lo que tu sp realiza es de las buenas practicas.

```
/****************************************  NOTAS SOBRE LA DOCUMENTACIÓN****************************************************
Si el sp sufre un cambio, respecto a la estructura es recomendable aumentar un 1 a la versión ejemplo de 1.0 a 2.0
Si el sp sufre un cambio que no afecta a la estructura como una validación es recomendable poner 1.1 y así sucesivamente*/

-- EXEC SP_HELPTEXT  [dbo].[NameSp]
-- Ejecución del sp
-- EXEC [dbo].[NameSp] Campos.......
-- Descripción : Procedimiento almacenado para realizar Insert en JOB
--
-- Ver   Persona        Fecha                   Descripción
-- ---   ----------     ----------              --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- 1.0                  14/10/2019               Creado

CREATE PROC [dbo].[NameSp]
--@Param1 INT
--,@Param2 INT
--,@Param3 NVARCHAR(50)   AQUI SE PONEN LOS PARAMETROS EN CASA DE NECESIAR
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO TK_DT_RECORDS(
    [TK_DT_RECORDS_ID],
    [ACTIVITY_DATE],
    [CONTENT],
    [TK_HD_TICKETS_ID],
    [NOTE],
    [USER_UPDATE],
    [TK_CT_STATUS_ID],
    [TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID],
    [TK_CT_SERVICES_ID],
    [TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID],
    [TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID],
    [TK_CT_SUBSERVICES_ID]
)
SELECT 
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_DT_RECORDS_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[ACTIVITY_DATE],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[CONTENT],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_HD_TICKETS_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[NOTE],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[USER_UPDATE],
    'CDO',
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_CT_SERVICES_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_CT_SUBSERVICES_ID]
FROM TK_HD_TICKETS AS TICKETS
INNER JOIN TK_DT_RECORDS 
    ON TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
WHERE 
    TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID = (
        SELECT MAX (TK_DT_RECORDS_ID) 
        FROM TK_DT_RECORDS 
        WHERE TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID 
    )
    AND (TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_CT_STATUS_ID = 'TMN') 
    AND (TK_DT_RECORDS.ACTIVITY_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE()))
END
```

> Te agrego lo mismo pero explicando un poco lo de los parametros que se
>   pueden enviar a un sp para que tu puedas usar dentro de el para las
>   operaciones que tu necesites.

```
/****************************************  NOTAS SOBRE LA DOCUMENTACIÓN****************************************************
Si el sp sufre un cambio, respecto a la estructura es recomendable aumentar un 1 a la versión ejemplo de 1.0 a 2.0
Si el sp sufre un cambio que no afecta a la estructura como una validación es recomendable poner 1.1 y así sucesivamente*/

-- EXEC SP_HELPTEXT  [dbo].[NameSp]
-- Ejecución del sp
-- EXEC [dbo].[NameSp] Campos.......
-- Descripción : Procedimiento almacenado para realizar Insert en JOB
--
-- Ver   Persona        Fecha                   Descripción
-- ---   ----------     ----------              --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- 1.0                  14/10/2019               Creado

CREATE PROC [dbo].[NameSp]
@ParametroFecha DATE --En este caso le estamos diciendo que el sp podra recibir un parametro de tipo fecha, Nota* Pueden ser NVARCHAR,INT,DECIMAL ETC.
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO TK_DT_RECORDS(
    [TK_DT_RECORDS_ID],
    [ACTIVITY_DATE],
    [CONTENT],
    [TK_HD_TICKETS_ID],
    [NOTE],
    [USER_UPDATE],
    [TK_CT_STATUS_ID],
    [TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID],
    [TK_CT_SERVICES_ID],
    [TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID],
    [TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID],
    [TK_CT_SUBSERVICES_ID]
)
SELECT 
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_DT_RECORDS_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[ACTIVITY_DATE],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[CONTENT],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_HD_TICKETS_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[NOTE],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[USER_UPDATE],
    'CDO',
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_CT_SERVICES_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID],
    TK_DT_RECORDS.[TK_CT_SUBSERVICES_ID]
FROM TK_HD_TICKETS AS TICKETS
INNER JOIN TK_DT_RECORDS 
    ON TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
WHERE 
    TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID = (
        SELECT MAX (TK_DT_RECORDS_ID) 
        FROM TK_DT_RECORDS 
        WHERE TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID 
    )
    AND (TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_CT_STATUS_ID = 'TMN') 
    AND (TK_DT_RECORDS.ACTIVITY_DATE < @ParametroFecha) --Aqui te agrego como lo podriamos usar si asi lo necesitaras le estamos pasando el parametro que nos llego del sp.
END

GO
--Para ejecutarlo seria algo como 
DECLARE @FechaDATE DATE =DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE())

EXEC [dbo].[NameSp] @FechaDATE --Mandamos el parametro que el SP recibe
```

Saludos

Comment: Listo revisalo y si tienes dudas con confianza